# Format String to HH:mm in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, format

My code:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-09-01 00-32-40")
```

Result: **2015-08-31 17:32:40**

But I want get result like this: **17:32**. How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're trying to get an `NSDate` and not a string representation, printing the `NSDate` will always show the full date time. To just show the hours and minutes, you'll have to create a string representation using an "HH:mm" date format, ex:

```
// Your original code
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-09-01 00-32-40")

// To convert the date into an HH:mm format
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
println(dateString)
```

Not sure why you're looking to get a result of "17:32", but this will produce "00:32" as a result from the original "00-32" portion of the string.

Comment: I use this before I ask:

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm";

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-09-01 00-32-40");                    
 
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!);

And it not work, now add line: dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" then it work fine; hmm. It's strange! sory about wrong "17:32" and "00:32"

Comment: @rome Yeah because you were trying to create a *date* from a string using an incomplete format, then trying to turn that date (which will always be in full date time format) into a string under the assumption that the original formatting still held.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: very comprehensive answer